# "On the report" or "In the report"?

Tags: prepositions

Should I use "on the report" or "in the report" ? 
in the below sentence:

> The material properties are presented in the report

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

> The material properties are presented **in the report**.

is correct. Think of opening up the report to some page with the information. You are now *in* the report.

*On the report* has more to do with describing the report as a whole:

> Do you have any comments **on the report**?